# how to access constructer object from array list. i am trying below logic but its not working

Tags: java

1. Write a Java program to calculate the total price of each book where book name
   //is unique. The basic code is given below.

EXPECTED OUTPUT
Total Selling price for Java Programming is 3640
Total Selling price for Learn PH is 640.50
Total Selling price for ReactJS for Dummies is 4800
Total Selling price for ANSI C is 1110

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class javaQ {
public static void main (String[] args) {

Book  prod1 = new Book ("Java Programming",520, 2);
Book  prod2 = new Book ("Learn PHP",213.50, 3);
Book  prod3 = new Book ("ReactJS for Dummies",320, 8);
Book  prod4 = new Book ("Java Programming",520, 5);
Book  prod5 = new Book ("ReactJS for Dummies",320, 7);
Book  prod6 = new Book ("ANSI C",222, 5);
List<Book > myList = new ArrayList<Book >();
myList.add(prod1);
myList.add(prod2);
myList.add(prod3);
myList.add(prod4);
myList.add(prod5);
myList.add(prod6);
int i=0,totalprice=0,totalqantity=0;
for(i=0;i<=myList.size();i++)
{
  String bookname=myList.getName();
  System.out.println(bookname);
  String price=myList.getPrice();
  String quantity=myList.getInt();
  if(bookname.equal.("Java Programing"))
  {
    totalprice=totalprice+
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Here is a syntax error:   totalprice=totalprice+. First try to fix it.

Comment: Hello, the code snippet is incomplete and does not compile.  You need to group by the book name and calculate total quantity and value per book, and you can use a `Map/HashMap` where you store new Book projects with accumulated quantity and value,

Answer (score 0):

You can write a pretty solution using the Maps

public static void main (String[] args) {

```
    Book  prod1 = new Book ("Java Programming",520, 2);
    Book  prod2 = new Book ("Learn PHP",213.50, 3);
    Book  prod3 = new Book ("ReactJS for Dummies",320, 8);
    Book  prod4 = new Book ("Java Programming",520, 5);
    Book  prod5 = new Book ("ReactJS for Dummies",320, 7);
    Book  prod6 = new Book ("ANSI C",222, 5);
    
    List<Book > myList = new ArrayList<Book >();
    myList.add(prod1);
    myList.add(prod2);
    myList.add(prod3);
    myList.add(prod4);
    myList.add(prod5);
    myList.add(prod6);
    
    
    
    Map<Book,Double> bookMap = new HashMap<>();
    
    for (Book book : myList) {
        bookMap.putIfAbsent(book, 0.0);
        bookMap.compute(book, (currentBook, price) -> price + currentBook.getPrice() * currentBook.getQuantity());
    }
    
    for(Entry<Book, Double> bookEntry : bookMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(bookEntry.getKey().getName() + " : " + bookEntry.getValue());
    }
    
}
```

You have to implement the equals and hashcode method in class of Book too.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Book other = (Book) obj;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `Map<String, Book>` to access a book info with accumulated data by the book name.  You can use a `TreeMap` then the keys will be sorted alphabetically.
2. For each book, check if a book with the given name exists in the map, if not, create a new instance of `Book`
3. Add the quantity and price to the book in the map.
4. Print map entries.

```java
Map<String, Book> totals = new TreeMap<>();
for (Book book : myList) {
    Book total = totals.getOrDefault(book.getName(), new Book(book.getName(), 0, 0));
    total.setInt(total.getInt() + book.getInt());
    total.setPrice(total.getPrice() + book.getPrice() * book.getInt());
    totals.putIfAbsent(book.getName(), total);
}

for (Map.Entry<String, Book> entry : totals.entrySet()) {
    Book total = entry.getValue();
    System.out.printf("Total Selling Price for %s is %.2f%n", 
        total.getName(), total.getPrice());
}
```

In the previous code snippet it is assumed that class `Book` has the following getters for price and quantity:

```java
public class Book {
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;
    public Book(String name, double price, int quantity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public double getPrice() { return price; }
    public void setPrice(double price) { this.price = price; }

    public int getInt() { return quantity; }
    public void setInt(int quantity) { this.quantity = quantity; }
}
```